# Need to save a JSON resoponse in a list and pass the stored list of items for each request in Jmeter

Tags: jmeter, jmeter-5.0

I have a json response like below

[
{
"firstName": "William",
"lastName":"Shakespeare",
"Title": "Mr",
"id": "1",
"books": [
{
"id": "WS1",
"title": "King John",
"year":"1596"
},
{
"id": "WS2",
"title": "Julius Caesar",
"year": "1599"
},
{
"id": "WS3",
"title": "Romeo and Juliet",
"year": "1595"
}
],
"Nationality": "English"
}
]

In the above response i have 3 ids, i need to store them as a array or list. Then i have 3 http requests, i need to pass each id to each requests respectively.

How to store the list using any post processor and pass the ids to each request in a linear way

Answer (score 0):

Use JSON extractor

- name: `id`
- JSON Path expressions: `$[*].books[*].id`
- Match No: -1

[image]
Access to each value:

```
id_1=WS1
id_2=WS2
id_3=WS3
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

1. Add [JSON Extractor](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/json-extractor) as a child of the request which returns that JSON and configure it as follows:

   [image]

   Textual form of the JsonPath expression just in case: `$..books.*.id`
2. In order to iterate the extracted IDs you can use [ForEach Controller](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#ForEach_Controller)

   [image]

Demo:

[image]

If you need to access individual values without iterating you can use `${ID_1}`, `${ID_2}`, etc. [JMeter Variables](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html) references.